# Ionic 2 drop down with search

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I use Ionic 2 to create fill form.
One of the field contain list custom data
I want to enable the user to choose field from dropdown.
But I want to implement drop down with search.

I try to find some kind of this implementation but there is no good reference for that.

Is Ionic 2 support dropdown with search?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no dropdown with search in Ionic, but there's a couple ways you can do this:

1 - Create a [Custom Component](https://www.joshmorony.com/custom-components-in-ionic-2/).

2 - Use a [Popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/).

For your case i think a popover can do the trick since it's a page component whose is addapted to fit in the popover dimensions and you can simply use a searchbar and a list inside of it to create a dropdown.

Hope this helps.